# install maven in docker

Tags: docker, maven, ubuntu

I am trying to install and build one file using maven in Dockerfile, but getting an error `mvn not found`...
I referred to some articles but I did not find anything

can anyone please help me to why I am getting this and how to solve this?

my code

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER ganeshthirumani
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget
ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"
#create a dir foe maven in opt
RUN mkdir /opt/maven
RUN mkdir /usr/share/maven
#RUN mkdir /usr/share/maven
#dwnl maven using link in tmp
RUN wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.4-bin.tar.gz -O /tmp/maven.tar.gz
#extract the file
RUN cd /tmp && tar xvf maven.tar.gz
#copy the file into opt/maven
RUN cp -R /tmp/apache-maven-3.8.4/* /usr/share/maven/
#RUN cp /opt/files/* /usr/share/maven
# Install OpenJDK-8
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && \
    apt-get clean;
    
# Fix certificate issues
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install ca-certificates-java && \
    apt-get clean && \
    update-ca-certificates -f;

# Setup JAVA_HOME -- useful for docker commandline
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME

#dwnl zip and move to /opt/files
RUN mkdir /opt/files
RUN  wget <this is my zip file> -O /tmp/zip_file.zip
RUN cp /tmp/zip_file.zip /opt/files/


ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"

RUN mvn clean install -Pdevelopment
#RUN mvn clean install -Pdeployment 


CMD ["mvn", "--version"]
```

and while building...

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  97.28kB
Step 1/20 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> d13c942271d6
Step 2/20 : MAINTAINER ganeshthirumani
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 83dbc04930a4
Step 3/20 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5a26c629963f
Step 4/20 : ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fea8fd2bb7f6
Step 5/20 : RUN mkdir /opt/maven
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 16a42d6b96c3
Step 6/20 : RUN mkdir /usr/share/maven
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 012f68749248
Step 7/20 : RUN wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.4-bin.tar.gz -O /tmp/maven.tar.gz
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dc498bb88baf
Step 8/20 : RUN cd /tmp && tar xvf maven.tar.gz
 ---> Using cache
 ---> be08499a07db
Step 9/20 : RUN cp -R /tmp/apache-maven-3.8.4/* /usr/share/maven/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7a705ce7213d
Step 10/20 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk &&     apt-get clean;
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 452e0b263645
Step 11/20 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install ca-certificates-java &&     apt-get clean &&     update-ca-certificates -f;
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d65d98457da5
Step 12/20 : ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b8cacc77d6b0
Step 13/20 : RUN export JAVA_HOME
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1a5918571b65
Step 14/20 : RUN mkdir /opt/files
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 66d092f96235
Step 15/20 : RUN  wget https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IutshyYqlcTw_MkfC1NJzU9AH8B-W2Fa/view?ts=61f24be4 -O /tmp/zip_file.zip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7180fa09993b
Step 16/20 : RUN cp /tmp/zip_file.zip /opt/files/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bc861eb85449
Step 17/20 : ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
 ---> Using cache
 ---> be97d22b8558
Step 18/20 : ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7874ed478f2f
Step 19/20 : RUN mvn clean install -Pdevelopment
 ---> Running in 5b58132ba431
/bin/sh: 1: mvn: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c mvn clean install -Pdevelopment' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

and I have seen that the basic directories are:
for maven home MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
for config---> MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2 and where user_home_dir is a root

thanks in advance

Comment: Is there reason not to use ready-to-use Maven containers ? https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/

Comment: Apart from @khmarbaise 's good suggestion, did you make any symbolic link to your maven executable? Unzipping something to /opt is not the equivalent of installing something in linux.

Comment: @khmarbaise  thanks for responding,
but I am trying to do it from scratch that's why not using the ready-to-use containers, and could you please tell me what steps do I have to take to make the container run,

Comment: @JustLudo is creating a symbolic link mandatory for maven to run? In my opinion, it is used for future updates. is that wrong? I also used `RUN mvn clean install -Pdevelopment` to build the file...is not a correct way?

Comment: First you download the Maven distribution which is fine but I strongly recommend to check the hashes of the files (https://downloads.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.4-bin.tar.gz.sha512) furthermore you have not added the MVN location to your `PATH` or even better within a container call only with an absolute path.. The `MAVEN_HOME` is not needed also the `install` does not makes sense because it would install the artifacts in your cache (of your container)..

Comment: Also I would download to `/usr/share` and unpack there so you get `/usr/share/apache-maven-3.8.4` location where I would create a link `/usr/share/maven` etc. Also multi stage build help to clean up the container...